# Why does python not working?

Tags: python, web, apache2, mod-python

I don't know why python isn't working with apache in ubuntu.

I've got python and libapache2-mod-python installed.

My default config file:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AlowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

# Python
AddHandler mod_python .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
PythonDebug On
```

My Error log is empty.

I've got python module enabled.

A simple python file:

```
def index(req):
    return "TEST";
```

But when accessing from webserver it has no response.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: You have defined a function, but have never called it. You need to call your function to see some output

Comment: And, `mod_python` is really dead, use `mod_wsgi` instead.

Comment: So which should be the configuration for apache to run python apps with mod_wsgi ?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function, that's good!
Now, just call it. Like this:

```
def index():
    return "TEST"

index()
```

(Note that unlike C, you do not need `;` at the end of statements in python)